# Flask, can not get the file part with request.files

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Here is my HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Picture
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/picture" method="post">
        <div>
            <p>Profile picture (32mb max).</p>
            <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the .py :

```
import sqlite3
import traceback
import sys
import os

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, session, request, flash
from application import profileName, uploadPicture, profilePicture, allowed_file
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

# Set Blueprints
picture = Blueprint('picture', __name__,)

@picture.route("/picture", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def pictureFunction():

    if request.method == "POST":      

        # check if the post request has the file part
        if "picture" not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect("/picture")

        file = request.files["picture"].read()

        # if user does not select file, browser also submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == "":
            flash("No selected file")
            return redirect("/picture")

        # Check if all conditions are satisfied
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join("/static", filename))
        return print(filename)
```

When I try to upload a .jpg (allowed file), I always end up in having: "No file part" of the first "if".

I don't understand why. Can somebody help me figure out why I can't upload this file?

Comment: Can you add a debug line `print(request.files)` directly after `if request.method=='POST':`, upload a jpeg, and add the output of this debug line to your question.

Comment: here it is: ```ImmutableMultiDict([])```

Comment: Something's not right there.  You should be seeing something like: `ImmutableMultiDict([('picture', <FileStorage: 'some_file.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>)])`.  EDIT: think I solved it, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enctype` attribute should be part of the `<form>` tag, not your file `<input>`:

So instead do something like:

```
    <form action="/picture" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <p>Profile picture (32mb max).</p>
            <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Indeed: 
`
ImmutableMultiDict([('picture', <FileStorage: '162A0049.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>)])
`

Comment: @Benoît Nice one!  If this has solved your issue, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Done. Accepted as answer.